# Unit test for Windows Strore Apps deletes Local Storage

Tags: unit-testing, windows-store-apps

I have created a test project for Windows Store App. There is a method `CreateDB` which creates a SQLite database. In my test project I have written a test method which calls the `CreateDB` method and checks if the database is created.

When I execute this test method everything goes well, but as soon as the test execution ends the Local Storage gets deleted.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the test framework is designed to create and remove the data

What I usually do in this case is serialize out the object or just convert it to a byte array, then I put a break point just before the end of the method, debug, break there, and copy the value out to a file.

Comment: ok, I created a method which creates a database and marked it as `TestInitialize` so that the db is created every time a test is run.